Flowbite is not working on mobile chrome browser but works on firefox "Works fine on laptop and when checked for reponsiveness"
Flowbite is not working on mobile chrome browser but works on firefox (Works fine on laptop and when checked for reponsiveness)
i expect any knows this problem's solution and anybody face this type of problem
please answer the question if any body knows
